# How can correct these lines of sh script to avoid "syntax error: unexpected end of file"

Tags: bash, shell, csh

```bash
#!/bin/sh

init=step5_input
rest_prefix=step5_input
mini_prefix=step6.0_minimization
equi_prefix=step6.%d_equilibration
prod_prefix=step7_production
prod_step=step7


# Minimization
gmx grompp -f ${mini_prefix}.mdp -o ${mini_prefix}.tpr -c ${init}.gro -r ${rest_prefix}.gro -p topol.top -n index.ndx
gmx mdrun -v -deffnm ${mini_prefix}

# Equilibration
cnt=1
cntmax=6

while [ ${cnt} <= ${cntmax} ]
    @ pcnt = ${cnt} - 1
    istep=`printf ${equi_prefix} ${cnt}`
    pstep= `printf ${equi_prefix} ${pcnt}`
    if [ ${cnt} == 1 ] then pstep=${mini_prefix}

    gmx grompp -f ${istep}.mdp -o ${istep}.tpr -c ${pstep}.gro -r ${rest_prefix}.gro -p topol.top -n index.ndx
    gmx mdrun -v -deffnm ${istep}
    @ cnt += 1
end

# Production
cnt=1
cntmax=10

while [ ${cnt} <= ${cntmax} ]
    @ pcnt = ${cnt} - 1
    istep=${prod_step}_${cnt}
    pstep=${prod_step}_${pcnt}

    if [ ${cnt} == 1 ] then
        pstep=`printf ${equi_prefix} 6`
        gmx grompp -f ${prod_prefix}.mdp -o ${istep}.tpr -c ${pstep}.gro -p topol.top -n index.ndx
    else
        gmx grompp -f ${prod_prefix}.mdp -o ${istep}.tpr -c ${pstep}.gro -t ${pstep}.cpt -p topol.top -n index.ndx
    endif
    gmx mdrun -v -deffnm ${istep}
    @ cnt += 1
end
```

Comment: I'm not very familiarized with `csh/tcsh` but to assign variables in that shell it should be with `set varname = value` (If I use your syntax I get an error: `command not found`). Are you sure you are using `csh`?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Where and why are you using  `@`  ?  I'm not sure if in `csh` it's valid to use `@` as you have. The `@` is valid to get all the values of  arguments you pass to a shell script.

Comment: I'm not sure if "@"  can be used in `csh`. However, do you want to convert to `sh` or `bash`? The title says `bash` but the shebang says `sh` (`/bin/sh`) ?

Comment: About the `if` statement, this must have `fi` to close the condition. With your code I'm not sure where the `if` statements must be closed. Can you provide more detailed code? Because `${equi_prefix}` I don't know what means but it seems that the `printf` is redundant in your code.

Comment: I have updated the codes!

Comment: Thanks!  I see several mistakes/syntax errors. I will try to provide a valid script.

Comment: And the error message with line number is …

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you all for your support. I duly appreciate it. I have learned a lot, and the answer provided has solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code contains several mistakes. The `@` I'm not sure what means in `csh` or if this one is valid.
There are some differences in the syntax between the different shells so you should take a look at the syntax used in `sh`, `bash`, `zsh`, `dash`, etc.

This is a valid syntax for your `sh` script:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

init=step5_input
rest_prefix=step5_input
mini_prefix=step6.0_minimization
equi_prefix=step6.%d_equilibration
prod_prefix=step7_production
prod_step=step7


# Minimization
gmx grompp -f ${mini_prefix}.mdp -o ${mini_prefix}.tpr -c ${init}.gro -r ${rest_prefix}.gro -p topol.top -n index.ndx
gmx mdrun -v -deffnm ${mini_prefix}

# Equilibration
cnt=1
cntmax=6

while [ ${cnt} -le ${cntmax} ]; do
    pcnt=$[ cnt - 1 ]
    istep=$(printf ${equi_prefix} ${cnt})
    pstep=$(printf ${equi_prefix} ${pcnt})

    #One liner if statement:
    if [ ${cnt} == 1 ]; then pstep=${mini_prefix}; fi

    gmx grompp -f ${istep}.mdp -o ${istep}.tpr -c ${pstep}.gro -r ${rest_prefix}.gro -p topol.top -n index.ndx
    gmx mdrun -v -deffnm ${istep}
    ((cnt += 1))

done

# Production
cnt=1
cntmax=10

while [ ${cnt} -le ${cntmax} ]; do
    pcnt=$(( cnt - 1))
    istep=${prod_step}_${cnt}
    pstep=${prod_step}_${pcnt}

    if [ ${cnt} -eq 1 ]; then
       pstep=$(printf ${equi_prefix} 6)
       gmx grompp -f ${prod_prefix}.mdp -o ${istep}.tpr -c ${pstep}.gro -p topol.top -n index.ndx
    else
        gmx grompp -f ${prod_prefix}.mdp -o ${istep}.tpr -c ${pstep}.gro -t ${pstep}.cpt -p topol.top -n index.ndx
    fi
    gmx mdrun -v -deffnm ${istep}
    cnt=$[ cnt += 1 ]
 done
```

**While**
A valid syntax for a `while` statement should be:

```bash
while [ expr ]; do
 code
done

#Or
while [ expr ]
do
 code
done
```

So if you want to compare number you should use:

1. `-le` means little or equals than
2. `-eq` means equals
3. `-lt` means little than
4. `-ge` means great or equals than
5. `-gt` means great than

**If**
A valid syntax for a `if` statement should be:

```bash
if [ expr ]; then
 code
fi

#or

if [ expr ]
then
 code
fi
```

The `expr` to compare numbers is the same as the `while` expr.

**Math operations**
You have several ways to use math operations in your code, in this script I've used two ways:

```
sum=$[ expr ]
#E.g.
pcnt=$[ cnt - 1 ]
```

And

```
sum=$(( expr ))
#E.g.
pcnt=$(( cnt - 1))

#or if you are not assign a value:
((expr))
#E.g.
((cnt += 1))
```

**Setting variables**
When you are setting some variable you must be careful with the spaces, if you run:

```bash
val = 10
```

That will cause an error: *command not found*. So the valid syntax is:

```
val=10
val='something'
val="something"
val=$(command)
val="$(command)"
val=`command`
val="`command`"
```

And about run commands to assign their output to a variable I see you have:

```
istep=`printf ${equi_prefix} ${cnt}`
```

Instead of using **val=`` `command` ``** you should use `val=$(command)`, which is more recommendable:

```
istep=$(printf ${equi_prefix} ${cnt})
```